# ValueError: could not convert string to float: fichero

Tags: python-3.x, string, archivo, matrices, float

Tengo un fichero matrix.txt con la siguiente matrix:

-----------------matrix.txt------------

```
[[ 2.94795074e+00  3.15288849e-02 -8.67170450e+02]
 [-2.21123258e-17  2.94877180e+00 -5.95651904e+02]
 [ 1.49601560e-04  1.52843706e-04  1.00000000e+00]]
```

este se encuentra en string y al intentar convertirla a float32 para multiplcarla con otra matrix me muestra este error...

```
matrix_file = np.array(matrix_file_l,  dtype="float32")
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[[-5.62093010e+01  5.75074002e+01  4.80460426e+03]\n'


p_homo = np.array([[1], [1], [1]])    
file = open('matrix.txt', 'r')
matrix_file_l =list()
matrix_file_l = file.read()
matrix_file = np.array(matrix_file_l,  dtype="float32")

def mult_matrix(matrix1, matrix2):
    matrixx = np.empty([len(matrix1), len(matrix2[0])])
    for i in range(len(matrix1)):
        for j in range(len(matrix2[0])):
            for k in range(len(matrix2)):
                matrixx[i][j] += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j]
    return matrixx

matrix = mult_matrix(matrix_file, p_homo)
```

como convertir en este caso la matrix para que mantenga un formato dtype=float32 y de tamanno 3x3 gracias de antemano y saludos